# Solving a physics equation in Python

Tags: python, physics

I'm fairly new to Python, and I got an idea to write a program to solve the Kinematic Equations used in physics.

```
vi = input("What is the initial velocity?")

if vi == "/":
    dontuse = "vi"
else:
    pass
```

I used this code for each of the values needed (Displacement, Initial Velocity, Final Velocity, Acceleration, and Time)

If the user inputs / as the value, it will not be used in the equation, so I wrote a small assignor to decide which equation to use.

```
if dontuse == "a":
    eq3()
elif dontuse == "d":
    eq4()
elif dontuse == "vf":
    eq1()
elif dontuse == "t":
    eq2()
```

Initial Velocity (vi) is used in every equation, so I didnt need to add one for that.

```
def eq1():
    # d = Vi*t + 1/2*a*t^2
    print("Equation 1!")
    answer = # d = Vi*t + 1/2*a*t^2
    print("Your answer is:", answer)
```

**My question is here, how would I insert the values of the other variables into an equation that the comupter could solve, then print out?**

It may seem like a basic question, but I wasnt sure how to do algebra like this with with Python.

Comment: Can you please **bold** what you are asking?

Comment: It sounds like you might want something like [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: `**` is equivalent to `^` in your example all the other operators are equivalent

Comment: @Berci, there is no raw_input in python3

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow doesn't exist to teach you Python. Do some tutorials and learn the syntax. Note that ^ is not the exponent operator.

Comment: Well, in the end, StackOverflow *does* teach Python for a lot of people. For example by sentences as your last one . @Padraic, ah yes, sorry it was not entirely clear that Python3 was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> def eq1():
>     # d = Vi*t + 1/2*a*t^2
>     print("Equation 1!")
>     answer = # d = Vi*t + 1/2*a*t^2
>     print("Your answer is:", answer)
> ```

To solve the equation `d = Vi*t + 1/2*a*t^2`in python, you would do

```
answer = Vi*t + .5*a*(t**2)
```

How does this work??

1. Multiplies initial velocity by time
2. Multiplies 1/2 by a
3. Multiplies that quantity (step 2) by the square of t

For the other equations, you really want to solve for one variable, so:

```
t = (Vf-Vi)/a
```

Comment: The parens are redundant

Comment: I understand that the parenthesis are not required, but I like to use them to break apart the equation and make it easier to read.

Comment: why not use them everywhere then?

Comment: For someone that is not well aware of python syntax (OP), they may confuse the `**`, so I put that in parenthesis.

Comment: This is quite close to what I'm looking for, but part of it is that you will not always be solving for d. It is not uncommon to be solving for time for example, so you need the value of d in the equation.

Comment: @AlexBrown What is the equation in terms of `t`?  I'm willing to put it into python syntax if you give it to me.

Comment: t was actually a bad example, usually when solving for t, Vi will be 0 using these equations. But if you needed to solve for a, or something else on the right side, you would end up having to move parts of the problem over to the left side in order to solve it. I'm not sure how to do algebra like that using Python.

Comment: If you tell me the equations, I can transfer it to python

Comment: Not sure what is what.  Can you break the equations apart by spaces or by `--`

Comment: There are four main Kinematic Equations used, the thing with the equations is that you are not always solving for the item on the left side of the equation. The four equations are: d = Vit + .5at^2, Vf^2 = Vi^2 + 2ad, d = .5(Vi+Vf)t, and Vf = Vi + at. What I am asking is, for example, in the fourth equation, how would you do it if you needed to solve for t? I am not sure how I could subtract Vi from Vf, then divide that by a.

Comment: In python, your really want to have one variable completely isolated when solving for it (otherwise, things get ugly).  So, if you wanted to solve for `t` in `Vf = Vi +at`, you would do `(Vf-Vi)/a = t`

Comment: Oh okay sweet, that makes sense! I'll just add some more functions depending on what I am solving for. Cheers man, thanks for the help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Though am a newbie in coding, the following code might solve the problem:

## This function is to solve one kinematic equation `[ d = vi*t + 1/2*a*t**2 ]`, having Displacement (d), Initial Velocity(vi), Acceleration (a), and Time (t)  as variables.

```
def eq1( vi, t, a):
d= vi * t + 1/2 *a * t **2

print (d)
```

""" calling the function by putting the values of vi, t, and a.
 you can change the values of your own."""

```
eq1(3,4,5)
```

## For other equations with same variables, you need to put the equations after eq1 like d1="......." and print (d1) or for more variables in a equation, define another function having all variables like- `def eq2(vi, t,a, x)`.